# Changing currentTime using React Component State

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, react-redux, ruby-on-rails-5

Heres a [link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0vm011z0kv). I'm looking for the best way to manipulate a `<video>` element's currentTime. In my sandbox I've been able to do that by having a button call a function `seek()` which changes the state of `video`, a reference to `document.getElementById('video-player')`, see below.

```js
export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      source: props.source,
      timestamp: props.timestamp
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ video: document.getElementById('video-player') })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props !== prevProps) {
      this.setState(
        { timestamp: this.props.timestamp }, 
        () => { this.seek() }
      );
    }
  }

  seek = () => {
    console.log(this.state.timestamp)
    //works
    this.state.video.currentTime = 1;
    //doesn't work
    //this.state.video.currentTime = this.state.timestamp;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video 
          id='video-player'
          height='200px'
          src={this.state.source} 
          type='video/mp4'
          controls>
        </video>
        {/* I don't want this button. I want skip from the outside */}
        <button onClick={this.seek}>Skip Inside Component</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The thing I can't figure out is that I can only manage to change currentTime inside the component because for whatever reason, I can't assign `this.state.timestamp` to the currentTime of my `<video>` reference (`this.state.video.currentTime`).

Ultimately the component should receive `props.timestamp`, provided by Redux, call `seek()` inside `<VideoPlayer />` whenever Redux's state changes, and set the video's currentTime to `this.state.timestamp`.

Let me know if you guys need any more details. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The above has been answered but I'm still having an issue. The sandbox I shared and just fixed still won't work in my [rails project](https://github.com/gjaros/ow_coaching/tree/master/app/javascript/owc_post) though. I had a feeling it wouldn't. When one of the three buttons in `App.js` is clicked, the state changes in Redux and is successfully received by `<VideoPlayer>`. This is confirmed by my console.log inside of `seek()` which returns the corresponding button's value to the console. However, the video's currentTime still doesn't change. Any ideas here?

Comment: You should not modify state directly (this.state.video.currentTime = this.state.timestamp) use setState

Comment: It's not a good practice to keep entire vedio element in the state, just use ref instead, https://codesandbox.io/s/kxnpj0wwv

Comment: @Nisfan Thanks! I'll do that. I figured there was a better way. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mapStateToProps` your `state` **is** the `timestamp`, and not `state.timestampReducer`.

This should work:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    timestamp: state
  }
};
```

Comment: That did it...it's always something small. I'll award you your green check in 5 minutes.

Comment: make sure you understand why it is behaving like that. You exposed 1(global) reducer which is the `timestamp.js` reducer. sometimes we want multiple "chunks" of reducers inside 1 root reducer, we would use [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)

Answer (score 0):

react state typically is used for managing your UI state, like: pause, playing, currentTime etc, therefore you should avoid assigning the dom element to the state`this.setState({ video: document.getElementById('video-player') })`

if you want to change the state of react, **never use this.state=something** like your seek function does.
use setState function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use refs, not state, to access your video.

With Classes:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.videoRef = React.createRef();
}

...

this.videoRef.current.currentTime = this.state.timestamp;
```

With Hooks:

```js
const videoRef = useRef(null);

...

videoRef.current.currentTime = timestamp;
```

And implement with: